# How to make parallax background be taller than the dyanmicly sized foreground column

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am creating a parallax effect in pure css but I can't figure out how to get the background to span the full size of the foremost column.

Ideally I'd like to have the background be around 120% the height of the foreground column, so that there is always a background even when scrolled to the bottom. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="layer back background">
  </div>
  <div class="layer front">
    <div class="spread-out">A wall of text taller than the screen</div>
    <div class="spread-out">A wall of text taller than the screen</div>
    <div class="spread-out">A wall of text taller than the screen</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.base {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

.back {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -5px;
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    z-index: -1;
}


.background {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #333333);
}

.spread-out {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Comment: If you add a background color, you won't notice any significant change related to parallax. You will need to have a good background image to see its effect.

Comment: With a gradient (taller than the page) you'll notice the parallax effect.

Comment: I agree, you can replace the background-image code with your background-color code and then see the effect. Also, if you want you can check with background image and see the magic.

Comment: Commented why I don't think that quite works - the background image in a fixed position only provides a "static" parallax effect, not a dynamic one.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 120vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
```

set height to 120vh.

Comment: I think I'm looking for a solution that doesn't depend on the exact content I have in the front. If you add one more row to the front then this solution doesn't work.

Comment: I think you should use min-height:120vh. it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do it using a grid which enables sizing of the children relative to eachother instead of the page. This works no matter how tall the foreground box is.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "whole-grid";
}

.layer {
  grid-area: whole-grid;
}

.base {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

.back {
    content: " ";
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    z-index: -1;
}

.background {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #000000, #FFFFFF);
}

.spread-out {
  height: 50vh;
}
```